# Comparing 2 files using python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, tabs

I'm trying to compare 2 delimited files commonly csv/pipe files using python. Instead of line by line comparison I'm looking for cell to cell comparison(element to element).
My result should be

1. A mismatch file should be created
2. In the console it should display column name, row number, Source row element value and target row element value. 
   Can any one please help me regarding this?

**Sample code:**

```
import sys, csv ,operator
data = csv.reader(open('D:\ANACONDA\sam.csv'),delimiter=',')
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))    # 0 specifies according to first column we want to sort
print (sortedlist);
now write the sorte result into new CSV file
with open("NewFile.csv", "wb") as f:
 fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
 for row in sortedlist:
           fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

---

source File1:

```
NAME,AGE,CITY  
a,34,abc
```

Target File1:

```
NAME,AGE,CITY  
a,34,xys
```

Output should look like : 
Mismatch on column CITY, row number 25 , Source value is : abc and Target value is : xys

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
rowElementCompare(sourceRow, targetRow)
{
    row_length = min(len(sourceRow), len(targetRow))
    for i in range(row_length):
        if sourceRow[i] != targetRow[i]:
            return i
    return None
}

import csv, itertools

column_names = ['name','age','city']
source_data = csv.reader(open('source.csv', delimiter=',')
target_data = csv.reader(open('target.csv', delimiter=',')
counter = 1

for source_row,target_row in itertools.izip(source_data,target_data):
    comparison_result = None
    comparison_result = rowElementCompare(source_row, target_row)
    if comparison_result != None: #comparison_result is the column index at which the mismatch occured
        print "Mismatch in column %s on row number %d , source value %s, target value %s" % (column_names[comparison_result], counter, source_row[comparison_result], target_row[comparison_result])
    counter += 1
```

The assumption is that both the source and target files have columns in the same order or whatever sorting you do produces output where the column order is still preserved.

Also the comparison assumes that the element values are strings and not any other data types ( otherwise you should do the conversion of data types yourself.